# Using a google sheets javascript add on without publishing it to the public

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote a `google sheets javascript add on`.

I want to use it for my own personal use, and not publish it for review or to the public.

How do I make the add on work on the sheet that I designated it for, without having the script open in the background, or having to publish it to the add on store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use a script in one spreadsheet, you don't need to make it an "add-on". The "add-on" term describes a script packaged for others to use.

To begin with, the script should be *bound* to a spreadsheet, which simply means  it should be created by the Script Editor accessed from the spreadsheet via Tools menu.

To have a way to run the script from the spreadsheet without opening the Script Editor, include in it an `onOpen` function creating a menu. Example:

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Process Data", functionName: "processData"}, {name: "Clear Data", functionName: "clearData"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Script", menu);
}
```

After this, every time the spreadsheet is open, it will have a new menu item "Script" with "Process Data" and "Clear Data" in it. (Naturally, your names of items and functions that they call will be different).